# Selecting parents recursively (for ACL/Permissions system)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

### Important things

**Model `Category`:**

```
[Table("Category")]
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Children = new HashSet<Category>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Parent")]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Database entries:**

```
---------------------------------
| Id | Parent | Name            |
---------------------------------
|  1 |   NULL | Top Category    |
---------------------------------
|  2 |    1   | Second Category |
---------------------------------
|  3 |    2   | Third Category  |
---------------------------------
|  4 |    3   | Fifth Category  |
---------------------------------
```

### And now the problem...

**How i use a query like...**

```
SELECT "Name" FROM "Category" WHERE "Parent" IS NULL;
```

**with a query like...**

```
SELECT "c"."Id", "c"."Parent", "p"."Name" FROM "Category" "c" LEFT JOIN "Category" "p" ON "p"."Id" = "c"."Parent" WHERE "c"."Name" LIKE '%d%';
```

I want to select a category with all their parents recursively.
It would be really nice to have a LINQ query for that.

**Expected result is something like this:**

```
----------------------------------------------
| "c"."Id" | "c"."Parent" | "p"."Name"       |
----------------------------------------------
|    2     |    1         | Top Category     |
----------------------------------------------
|    3     |    2         | Second Category  |
----------------------------------------------
```

**Or with a group?**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| "c"."Id" | "c"."Parent" | GROUP_CONCAT(...)             |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|     2, 3 |         1, 2 | Top Category, Second Category |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

**The category "system" above is a example for a bigger plan...:**

( Is there a framework / nuget plugin which allow to use ACL/Permissions/Rights on objects which stored in database?
I have users and groups. Then i have folders and files. Each user or group can have rights for specific folder or file. You can enable heredity for file oder folder-permissions. And with this query i try to read all permissions for a user and a specific folder with all their parents... )

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
 var result = 
        from first in db.Category
        join second in db.Category on first.Id equals second.ParentId.GetValueOrDefault(0) 
        where first.name.Contains(parameter)
        select new
        { 
            Id = first.Id , 
            ParentId= second.ParentId ?? 0, 
            ParentName= second.Name
        };
```

I have used `second.ParentId.GetValueOrDefault(0)`  because the join is made on two differents types int and nullable of int

Comment: It doesnt work. I have no recursion. Your query selects only two entries. What if any searchs after `Cat`? Then the query should select all entries of the database because all entries matches `%Cat%`. But thanks. Maybe you know a recursive query for that. I want to select all childs of a category. For example the main category with all childs and the childs of their childs and the childs of the childs of the childs etc....